# layout.js - PrimeFaces.widget.Avalon not invoked

Tags: spring-boot, primefaces

i using Primefaces 8.0,Springboot 2.2.5.RELEASE
and Avalon 2.1.1.
after add layout.js in template.xml, layout.js not invoke the menu on the left hand side does not work anymore. When clicking on another element from the layout-tab-menu the CSS class active is not assigned to layout-tab-submenu. The menu-resize-btn does not work anymore.

[my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEhSa.png)

template.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title><ui:insert name="title">PrimeFaces Avalon</ui:insert></title>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#03A9F4"/>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="last">
    <h:outputScript name="js/nanoscroller.js" library="avalon-layout" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/layout.js" library="avalon-layout" />
    </f:facet>
    <ui:insert name="head"/>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div class="layout-wrapper menu-layout-static">
        <ui:include src="./topbar.xhtml" />

        <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />

        <div class="layout-main">
            <div class="layout-main-content">
                <ui:insert name="content"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <ui:include src="./footer.xhtml" />

    </div>

    <p:ajaxStatus style="width:32px;height:32px;position:fixed;right:7px;bottom:7px">
        <f:facet name="start">
            <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin ajax-loader" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="complete">
            <h:outputText value="" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:ajaxStatus>

    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/nanoscroller.css" library="avalon-layout" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/animate.css" library="avalon-layout" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/layout-blue-v4.css" library="avalon-layout" />
</h:body>
```

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>


<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
    <el-resolver>
        org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>

<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>
        org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory
    </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>

<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingPhaseListenerMulticaster</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

dependencies

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>psa</groupId>
<artifactId>empower-web</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<name>empower-web</name>
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.20</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>avalon</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.SP1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

ServletCustom

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean facesServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new FacesServlet(), "*.xhtml");
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
    return servletContext -> {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", "Development");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("facelets.DEVELOPMENT", "true");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE", "true");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION", "true");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.THEME", "avalon-blue-v4");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD", "client");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.FONT_AWESOME", "true");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("primefaces.UPLOADER", "commons");
        servletContext.setInitParameter("org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING", "true");
    };
}

@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<>(new ConfigureListener());
}
```

Question: What am I missing to register or configure?

Comment: Does it work if you use an empty faces-config? Does it work if you don't use includes? Does it work if you use an empty web.xml? Does it work if you don't use spring-boot? (you don't tag the Q  spring-boot so you assume it is unrelated, then remove all code and try with plain Spring in a deployale war and did you check for js/http errors? Please investigate more... Not the best of questions. Cheers!

Comment: Any progress to report? I did not downvote yet, but please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Comment: apparently I was due to lack of adding 
<pu:menu widgetVar="me"/>
after added then layout.js no issue.